# Corpus of baby-talk or motherese

Tags: corpora, language-acquisition, resource-request

Baby-talk or motherese is the language that parents tend to use when addressing preverbal or just-starting-to-speak children. What are the fundamental features or rules that define this subset of a language? Is there a publicly available corpus/dataset for it?

I am primarily interested in English or rules and features that would apply to the motherese of most languages. However, rules or corpora from other languages are fine as answers, too.

Comment: It's notable that the use of motherese is not universal. You may be surprised to learn that some cultures do not talk to babies.

Comment: @hippietrail yeah, I might ask another question about universality later. I really hope to target this question at the ones that do, since it seems that most languages (where most is by number of speakers) do.

Comment: @downvoter there is a downvote on the question, I was curious about the rational (usually people say why they downvote) so that I could improve the question. Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, the way a baby talks is idiosyncratic.

Comment: @Peter: While I believe all babies have their own "idiolect" of babytalk they all go through the same stages of tuning in to the sounds of the language(s) in which they live.

Comment: Generally this is now referred to as 'child-directed speech' or 'child language input', rather than 'motherese', because 'motherese' generally describes a particular style of input characterized by e.g. exaggerated intonation. Not all cultures use 'motherese' to address children. (But there are very few corpora that are not English-based.)

Comment: @hippietrail: can you please indicate which cultures don't talk to babies? it would be interesting to see.

Comment: @NikhilBellarykar: I don't know off the top of my head but I've most definitely read it multiple times in at least pop linguistics literature. I think Africa or other places with developing economies were specifically mentioned. Probably writers such as David Crystal and Steven Pinker. [Googling "culture lack motherese"](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=culture+lack+motherese) seems to work though.

Comment: @NikhilBellarykar: Try this link which includes "Motherese is not a universal phenomenon: some cultures and communities either lack Motherese all together - parents speak to their children with no peculiar ..." http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=culture+lack+motherese&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEcQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhttp-server.carleton.ca%2F~ecorazza%2Fonline_courses%2FMind_World_and_Knowledge%2F10%2520The%2520Poverty%2520of%2520the%2520Stimulus%2520Argument.ppt&ei=ccQvT4bfFMm80QWpi8CtCA&usg=AFQjCNEs5J-c1WZd2yLryas3N2uD5TnCcQ&sig2=Yx6jo7KHn2QqcS4EUw42mA

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Deb Roy work prash brings up is certainly interesting, but it is just one child in one language. The standard for researchers that study language acquisition is to use the [CHILDES Database](http://childes.talkbank.org/) (MacWhinney, 2000). CHILDES provides downloadable transcripts, video, and audio files mostly comprised of conversations between caretakers and children in many languages and at many ages.

As for Motherese itself, the seminal paper on this is [*Mother, I'd Rather Do it Myself*](http://pages.pomona.edu/~rt004747/lgcs123read/NewportEA77.pdf) (Newport, Gleitman, and Gleitman, 1977). While the topic has been revisted many times since, the general conclusions of that work still stand. It was the first paper to show that Motherese is "tuned" to the stage of acquisition of the child is in. That is, Motherese isn't a fixed style of speaking; we vary it with respect to how much the child we're talking to knows about language.

Some characteristics of Motherese pointed out in that article:

1. While utterances are short, they are not necessarily syntactically simple. There are arguments made that the amount of movement required in a derivation of those sentences on average exceeds that of adult-to-adult utterances, largely because of the high number of questions.
2. Utterances are heavily focused on directing the actions of children when they are younger, and change to contain more declaratives as they get older.
3. It would appear that Motherese is optimized for easy processing rather than syntactic complexity. That is, utterances are short and contain few morphemes, but often more complex short utterances are used as opposed to simpler, longer ones.

Of course, the concept of "simple" is not straightforward; in the cited article it has to do in particular with the transformations common of syntactic theory of the time. Later papers questioned these ideas, but the consensus is that for whatever definition of "simple" you choose with respect to a grammar these general conclusions still hold.

There are of course other phonological and phonetic characteristics of Motherese. The exaggerated prosody (the intonation of a sentence) and facial expressions are an important part of it as well. So if you want to find a broad set of discussions on Motherese and rules, etc., I would recommend following the trail of papers that cite the one I list above. You can use [this Google Scholar link](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=5157312406828912975) to search among those articles.

Comment: Unfortunately Firefox says Server not found for the CHILDES link.

Comment: @learner I've updated the CHILDES link as the old location is no longer in use. The new location is http://childes.talkbank.org/

Answer (score 4):

[Prof. Deb Roy](http://www.ted.com/speakers/deb_roy.html) has recorded every moment of his child growing up and acquiring a language — and that includes motherese, and everyone-else-ese. You can probably contact him for the corpus.

Answer (score 2):

Prof. Aylin Kuntay in Koç University has started a project to build the corpus of Turkish babies. The project has not been completed so the corpus is not available online.

Answer (score 1):

An eminent linguist Ashok Kelkar has made a rather detailed analysis of [Marathi baby talk](http://www.ciil-ebooks.net/html/Kelkar2/kelkar/b29.htm).

Take a look at point 3 onwards and you will find the vocabulary and whatnot. I agree that it is only for Marathi, but it is not restricted to one baby, and I, as a native Marathi speaker, can vouch for the ubiquity of the vocabulary given by him.